# how to manage filenames for gallery?

Tags: php, javascript, file-upload

the procedure:

i have a script which uploads images (via hmtl-form and php) for a gallery for something you can sell on the internet.

the uploaded files are stored to some temp folder. if the customer pays for posting the object online, a daemon, who crawls the directories, will then get the pictures and scale them to fit into several interfaces, which creates resized copies of each image, identified by a letter (o,l,s) and the image number 0,1,2,3...n
then you have something in a directory like

- o_0.jpg
- o_1.jpg
- l_0.jpg
- l_1.jpg
- s0.jpg
- s1.jpg

the problem:

there is also a preview mode where you can see how your article will be viewd later on (after paying). here the images i.e. l_1.jpg and s_1.jpg shell be displayed (in the several interfaces i.e. thumbnails). well they can be scaled by html, because its only a preview (can look awful, doesn't matter).

but the thing is, after uploading i only have the o_x.jpg s in my tmp directory. i don't want to copy them on the server to have also the l_x... and s_x....

so i could ask in my view if it is the preview and show then o_x.jpg s everywhere, the images occur. but the problem is, that those pictures are part of a js interaction skript, where the images displayed can be switched by user interaction, where i need to change img.src property. which would mean i have to check if it's a preview again.

the thing is, i don't like the idea of changing the code (in more then one file) so much and asking the same thing on more than one position only to be able to display the preview. has anyboy an idea how i can handle this at one central spot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onerror` did the trick ... woohooo
so i can use now:

```
`<img src="images/l_0.jpg" onerror="this.src='images/o_0.jpg'" alt="" />`
```